# Android back button clicked and var inside of the activity to live longer

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have a case where inside an `activity`, I have a variable (say `bindingManager`) to store the binding information between the application to a service. I understand that when the 'Back' `button` on the phone is clicked, the activity will be destroyed and so are all its member variables. If I want make these binding info stored in `bindingManager` persistent after the `activity` is destroyed, may I know where shall I move this variable (`bindingManager`) to?

Thanks
Regards
Hammer

Comment: shared preferences, or write it to a file!

Comment: inside onStop method will be better option !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think storing binding info. into the file, preferences, or DB would be annoying things.
It seems you have a service. So why don't let your service store information you want. And the [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) should be remote so it would live after an activity has dead.

I think you may need Messengers or AIDL to complete this work.

This is very short answer without specific codes. But you can make it work with this tiny hint.

Comment: thanks for the info. Currently our service is a bound service, as I need the app to interact with the service and started service cannot do this... it is a good idear to store all these mappings on service side, in this case,may need to create a dummy app to bind to the service, otherwise when all bounded apps are destroyed, service will be terminated as well?

Comment: Btw, a bit curious, if I click close btn, my activities and app are destroyed. Storing their mappings to services do not make sense right?

Comment: Your service is going to be a host service. Other services will be a clients services. So it's up to you to stop or keep your service when all bounded apps are destroyed. You decide.

Comment: I said "And the service should be remote so it would live after an activity has dead." It means.. the service will alive even after your activity finished. Because Marking a service as "remote" will produce two processes.

Comment: I got this from doc. /n

If we want to make this service run in a remote process (instead of the standard one for its .apk), we can use android:process in its manifest tag to specify one:

<service android:name=".app.MessengerService"
        android:process=":remote" />
Note that the name "remote" chosen here is arbitrary, and you can use other names if you want additional processes. The ':' prefix appends the name to your package's standard process name.